# Reading in a file causing a StackOverflowException in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, stack-overflow

I am currently working on a C# wpf project. The files are exported data from a database which are in the form of an SQL statement. For each line that the file reads in it executes the statement to perform the action on the database inside the MySQL server.

The task is run inside a background worker which reports progress, so each time a line has been executed on the MySQL Server it calls the progress changed event to update a progress bar so that the user known how much the program has restored to the server.

However, when it gets to a certain point the progress changed event crashes with a stack overflow exception. Below is the code that updates the progress bar which is where the stackoverflow exception occurrs.

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    window.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
    {
        progressRestore.IsIndeterminate = false;
        progressRestore.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblRestProgress.Content = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
        //lblRestProgressDesc.Content = "Row " + lineCount + " of " + totalRows;
        return null;
    }), null);
}
```

How can I resolve this exception? I have tried to run the garbage collector but I don't think this affects the stack so it didn't work and I have also tried adding a small delay to each line read but this doesn't seem to have helped either.

Comment: I dont think you need to invoke on the progress changed event from a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Boardy little confusing to me that e.progresspercentage treated as value probably as an integer type and at the same time in the next line as a string, unless C# automatically parses the percentage as it sees fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `window.Dispatcher.Invoke`, as `BackgroundWorker` already marshals the calls to `ProgressChanged` back to its original `SynchronizationContext`.  (This is assuming you're starting the BW from the UI thread...)

Try removing this, and just setting your values directly:

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     progressRestore.IsIndeterminate = false;
     progressRestore.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
     lblRestProgress.Content = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
     //lblRestProgressDesc.Content = "Row " + lineCount + " of " + totalRows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, not sure now why I put the event dispatcher code in, thought it came up with a thread ui interface error. Thanks for your help though